# How can we check the register value in inline-assembly in c?

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, keil

I'd like to simple inline assembly experiment in uVision with STM32F as the below code.

But I'v got a some problem with error message when I compile it.

```
unsigned int bar(unsigned int r0)

{
  unsigned int r1;
  unsigned int r4 = 1234;
__asm
{


    MOVS  r0,#0
    LDR   r1,[r0]     ; Get initial MSP value
    MOV   SP, r1
    LDR   r1,[r0, #4] ; Get initial PC value
    BX    r1
}

  return(r1);

}
```

I've got the below error messages when I compile it as the below.

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 5 (build 528)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Build target 'STM32F429_439xx'
compiling main.c...
../main.c(79): error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
                                LDR   r1,[r0]     ; Get initial MSP value
../main.c(80): error:  #20: identifier "SP" is undefined
                                MOV   SP, r1
../main.c(81): error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
                                LDR   r1,[r0, #4] ; Get initial PC value
../main.c(82): error:  #1084: This instruction not permitted in inline assembler
                                BX    r1
../main.c(71): warning:  #177-D: variable "r4"  was declared but never referenced
    unsigned int r4 = 1234;
../main.c(82): error:  #114: label "r1"  was referenced but not defined
                                BX    r1
../main.c: 1 warning, 5 errors
"STM32F429_439xx\STM32F429_439xx.axf" - 5 Error(s), 1 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:01
```

What am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a nagging feeling that what you're trying to do here isn't complete, and causing a soft reset might be better. However;

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124249383.htm

> The inline assembler provides no direct access to the physical
>   registers of an ARM processor. If an ARM register name is used as an
>   operand in an inline assembler instruction it becomes a reference to a
>   variable of the same name, and not the physical ARM register.

...

> No variables are declared for the sp (r13), lr (r14), and pc (r15)
>   registers, and they cannot be read or directly modified in inline
>   assembly code.

However, CMSIS provides the following:
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__Core__Register__gr.html#gab898559392ba027814e5bbb5a98b38d2

```
__STATIC_INLINE uint32_t __get_MSP(void)
{
  register uint32_t __regMainStackPointer     __ASM("msp");
  return(__regMainStackPointer);
}
```